# Range of character is positive then if i store a integer in it still it should print a value between(0-255).why Output is -24

Tags: c, arrays, char, output, signed

'''

```
void main()
{
   int i=1000;
   char c='A';
   c=i;
   printf("%d",c);
}
```

'''

> Output is -24
>
> > why this output when range of character is (0-255)

Comment: What makes you think the range of type `char` is 0 - 255?  Implementations are permitted to differ with respect to whether `char` is a signed or unsigned type, and when signed (which is common) its range is typically -128 - 127.  Your experiment seems to show that your implementation's `char` is signed.

Answer (score 2):

When explaining that behaviour, the following things need to be considered:

First, in an assignment like `c=i` in

```
int i=1000;
char c='A';
c=i;
```

we need to consider that `i` is converted to the type of `c` before assignment. Integral conversion is defined [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3) in an online C99 standard draft:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value
>   can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.60)
>
> **3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be
>   represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.**

So it is necessary to know if `char` is a singed integral type or not. This can differ from compiler to compiler, but it seems that your compiler considers type `char` as `signed char` by the default.

In case of `signed char`, the "result is implementation-defined", and we would need to have a look at the compiler's specification.

A common implementation is that the integral value 1000, which in binary is `00000011 11101000` is truncated to 8 bits and stored in the char value.

What `11101000` then means for a `signed char` is defined in the [representation of types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2):

> **6-2-6-2 Integer types**
>
> 2 For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation
>   shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the
>   sign bit. There need not be any padding bits; signed char shall not
>   have any padding bits. There shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit
>   that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the
>   object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are
>   M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M <=
>   N ). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value.
>   If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the
>   following ways:
>
> - the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and
>     magnitude);
> - **the sign bit has the value -(2M) (two's complement);**
> - the
>     sign bit has the value -(2M- 1) (ones' complement).
>
> Which of these
>   applies is implementation-defined, as ...

Again, the result is defined in by the implementation of the compiler; but a common interpretation is two's complement, interpreting the most significant bit as sign bit:

In your case, the 8 bits of `11101000` is one sign bit (set) and 7 bits of the remainder; the remainder is `1101000` which is 104; the actual value in two's complement is then -(127-104+1), which is -24.

Note that it is not clear that the result is -24; other compilers might yield different results.

There is even one more step to consider, as you print the signed character value using format specifier "%d":

```
printf("%d",c)
```

This means, that negative `signed char` value gets promoted to `int` type; but this will yield the "same" negative value then. I omit the explanation of "promotion" and why arguments in `printf` are promoted at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler by default considers the type `char` as a signed integer type similarly to the type `signed char`.

The range of values for the type signed char is

```
— minimum value for an object of type signed char
  SCHAR_MIN -127 // −(27 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type signed char
  SCHAR_MAX +127 // 27 − 1
```

From the C Standard (5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`)

> 2 **If the value of an object of type char is treated as a signed
>   integer when used in an expression, the value of CHAR_MIN shall be the
>   same as that of SCHAR_MIN and the value of CHAR_MAX shall be the same
>   as that of SCHAR_MAX.** Otherwise, the value of CHAR_MIN shall be 0 and
>   the value of CHAR_MAX shall be the same as that of UCHAR_MAX. 20) The
>   value UCHAR_MAX shall equal 2CHAR_BIT − 1.

Here is a demonstrative program where there is used the type `unsigned char` instead of the type `char`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 1000;
    unsigned char c;

    printf( "i = %#x\n", i );

    c = i;

    printf( "c = %d\n", c );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
i = 0x3e8
c = 232
```

As you can see an object of the type signed char can not hold such a big value as `232`. If you will subtract 232 from 256 you will get `24`. So this value and the value 232 used as an internal representation of signed char will get 0. So this internal representation of 232 interpreted as a signed value should be equal to -24 that is 24 + -24 = 0.

Comment: Re “Your compiler by default considers the type `char` as the type `signed char`”: `char` may be signed or unsigned, but, regardless, it is a distinct type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`. See C 2018 6.2.5 15 and footnote 45.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know this. So I provided a more accurate quote from the C Standard.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnBollinger said, the typical range of type `char`, which is usually signed, is -128 - 127. When you assign 1000(`1111101000` in binary) to the `char`, only the 8 least significant bits(assuming your `char`s are 8 bits) are kept leading to `11101000` in binary. This translates to -24 when it's printed as a signed integer.